# log4j create log file with timestamp in filename using ONLY log4j.xml

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to create a log file with a date appended to the filename such as `application.log.yyyymmdd`.

This is my current log4j.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="application.log" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
          <param name="ConversionPattern" 
              value="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n  %-5p %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

It is not creating `application.log.yyyymmdd` instead it is only generating `application.log`.

Is there another way to *only use* log4j.xml to achieve this?

Comment: it is always `applicaiton.log` for your current day's file, once rolls a day, it will append the date suffix.

Comment: i would like it to have the date suffix once the file is generated -without rolling the next day. is that possible?

Comment: Im afraid you cannot. DailyRollingFileAppender gives you the rolled logs with date pattern, but the current day is always `application.log`, without date.

Answer (score 1):

The log file is rolled out every day, and the current day's log file without date. Suppose current day is 2015-05-06, and at midnight, once it pass 23:59:59, log4j will backup the `application.log` into `application.log.2015-05-06` and the `application.log` file become logging for the new day, 2015-05-07, and son on

You should be aware `application.log` is current day's log file, so it does not matter it has a data suffix or not.

The following is what I am using for now, it is rolled a new file every day, and kept the log files for 30 days.

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>/data/log/logging.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
```

Comment: can i use `org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy` instead of `ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy`